Is this proof of the density of the rationals in the reals correct?
Theorem: For any 2 non-equal positive real numbers, there exists a rational number "between" them.
$ x , y \in \mathbb{R} $,
$ 0 \lt x \lt y \implies  \exists q \in \mathbb{Q} | x \lt q \lt y$
Proof:
$q$ can be expressed as a ratio of 2 non-zero natural numbers (since $q$ is not negative and by definition, rationals are ratios of integers).
Thus $q = \frac{m}{n} | m,n \in \mathbb{N \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}}$
Then $ x \lt \frac{m}{n} $, multiplying:
$nx \lt m$ or $n \lt m \cdot \frac{1}{x}$, but $n$ is a real number and so is $ \frac{1}{x} $, thus an existence of such an $m$ is guaranteed by the archimedean property.
Similarly, $ \frac{m}{n} \lt y $, multiplying: $ m \lt y \cdot n $ and again, the existence of such an $n$ is guaranteed by the archimedean property.
This really concludes the proof, quod erat demonstrandum.
I do believe this proof to be valid as $m$ and $n$ are not dependent on each other. First, the existence of $m$ is shown independently of the value of $n$, then vice versa.
Is my reasoning correct?

This proof shows that each of these inequalities can be satisfied, I think what would be worthwhile would be a one-liner to show how these both combined show that the inequalities are solved simultaneously. You kinda mention that in your comment after the proof, but to make it tight I would include a discussion of that in the proof itself

You're right. I was worried about this but I'm rather certain that they can be satisfied because in the first part (n < m/x), the value of n does not matter, what matter s is only the fact that it is a natural (thus real) number. Similarly in the second part and so, I do believe that the reasoning is not flawed.
I would of course, appreciate any criticism.

I think the reasoning is flawed. All you have shown is that there exist two (not necessarily equal!) rationals $p$ and $q$ such that $x<p$ and $q < y$. You do not show that $p=q$, you just happen to use the same symbols for the numerator and denominator of $p$ and $q$.

@whpowell96 I think the two inequalities can be rectified by using a selected value from the first one to pick a value of $m$ in the second one, but I agree as it stands the link isn't immediately obvious

@whpowell96
I've shown that whatever n is, there exists an m s.t. nx<m, then I've shown that whatever m is, there exists an n s.t. m < ny,
Dividing the first part, whatever n is, there exists an m s.t. x < m/n
Dividing the second part, whatever m is, there exists an n s.t. m/n < y
Thus, irrespective of n, there must exist an m and vice versa.
Is this not correct?

"q can be expressed as a...".   No.   It should be "If such a $q$ exists it could be express as a..."  and later "but n is a real number and so is 1x, thus an existence of such an m is guaranteed by the archimedean property." Only if you know that $n$ exists."Similarly, mn<y, multiplying: m<y⋅n and again, the existence of such an n is guaranteed by the archimedean property."  Only if you know that $m$ exist.  This seems circular.  It's probably valid and fixible but it seems you are relying too much on assuming what you want is true to begin with.

You have $m$ dependent on $n$ and $n$ dependent on $m$.  That doesn't hold.

@fleablood You're right. I've assumed existence from the start but if I'm not mistaken, such an assumption is only my poor use of words, not a requirement.

You still haven't shown that either $m$ or $n$ exist independently of the other. Something somewhere in their construction should depend only on $x$ and $y$

Yes, but it's a pet peeve of mine..... anyway.... I think you can fix the whole thing by noting $y-x > 0$ so by archemedian princimple there is an $m\in \mathbb N$ so that $m(x-y) > 1$ and  then... smooth sailing.

@whpowell96 Please, excuse my ignorance if what I say is wrong but I do believe that the first inequality is independent, it's because the value of n does not matter at all. What matters is only the fact that it is a real number. For inequality 2, the existence of m was established.

The value of $n$ matters.  If it didn't you could assume wolog it equals $1$ and your proof is any attempt to prove there is an INTEGER between any two reals.  You have to show that an $n$ exists at all in the first place.  You are in assuming that any such $n$ exists, essentially assuming what you want to prove.

Yes, of course the value of n matters, but not for the first inequality. If that helps, essentially what I did was claim that for any possible natural n, I can find an m, s.t. n<m/x, which is just the archimedean property.

That assumes you know that reals can be expressed as infinite decimals.  .... I definately wouldn't throw out the baby with the bathwater.  I'd fixe your issue.  What's wrong with $y-x >0$ so there exist an $m$ so that $m(y-x) > 1$ ?

Also.... "nx<m or n<m⋅1x, but n is a real number and so is 1x," you are assuming $x \ge 0$.

I am not assuming that. It was given in the theorem :)

You are setting this up as though $q$ exists, when that is what you need to prove.  That'd be okay, if I, the reader were to put, "If $q$ exists, then it would mean and require" before everything.  But it leads to an issue where you find $m$ based on assuming an $n$ already exists, and then showing an $n$ exist based on the $m$ you found.  That's fatal.
But this is fixible.
Now we know that $x< y$ so $y-x >0$ and if $y-x = d$ then for any $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $nx < ny$ and $ny - nx = nd$.   By the archemedian principal we can find an $n$ were $nd > 1$ and thus we can have $ny =nx + nd > 1+nx$.
Now we should have proven  that for any real $w$ and $w+1$ there must exist an integer $k$ so that $w < k \le w+1$.
So there exists an integer $m$ so that $nx < m \le nx + 1$ and so $nx < m \le nx+1 < ny$.
And so $x < \frac mn < y$.
.....
Of course we should probably review how we know that for ever $w$ then must exist and integer $k$ so that $w < k \le w+1$.
[The reals have least upper bound property.  let $S=\{n\in \mathbb Z| n\le w\}$. That's bounded above by $w$ so $u=\sup S$ exist.  Thus $u-1$ is not any upper bound and there exists and integer, $m$, in $S$ so that $u-1 < m$. But $m\in S$ so $u-1< m\le w$.  So $u< m+1\le w$.  But $u$ is an upper bound so $m+1\not \in S$ and $m+1 > 1$.  So $w < m+1 \le w$ and $k = m+1$ is the integer we needed.]

I do not agree that I am finding m based on assuming n exists, supposing q exists (and it is not given as you've said, that is why I said "supposing"), then there exists a natural m, such that n<m/x for any possible n. Perhaps my argument would be less confusing if I said there exists an m, such that k<m/x for all possible k.
Also, there exists an n such that m<ny for all possible m. Thus, arbitrarily setting k=n, the proof is really finished.
Your proof is really nice but it's almost everywhere (perhaps thanks to Rudin). I just wanted to do something new :).

But then you wouldn't have found either of the $m$ or the $n$.  How can you set $k =n$ when $n$ hasn't been found yet.  You start with $k$.  Then you find an $m$ so that $\frac mx > k$.  Then you find an $n$ so that $ny > m$.  And then you set $k = n$.  That's circular.  It's not guarenteed if you start with $k=1$.  You are taking it on faith there must be some $k$ were it works.  Your argument is like saying for any $n$ there is an $m$ where $m=n+1$ and for every $m$ there is an $n$ where $n = m+1$. Therefore there is some integer $n$ where $n = n+2$.

I'm not sure there can be any other type of proof.  The key thing is that there is a gap between $y$ and $x$.  By the arch. prin we can blow up the gap to any size we want so if there is any gap that's just "too big" to not have a rational, then every gap is too big to not contain a rational... another tack is $0<\frac 1{2n}<\frac 1n< y-x$ so $x<x+\frac 1{2n}<x+\frac 2{2n} < y$ and there must be a rational in between. I don't think we can bootstrap our way out of doing so blow the gap up and do a lowest integer trick.

Well, a converging series is possible.  But that's really boring.  But, boring, or not it's the most fundamentally true considering the very definition of a real number.
